# Error: Unknown provider: tProvider <- t angularJS in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a problem with angularjs. When the javascripts are minified I got this error "Error: Unknown provider: tProvider <- t" but when I disable minify my web app works. I know http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05 and I have done all of the tips. I also install https://github.com/jasonm/ngmin-rails that would format it for you but still I got this error. But when I click the error in the console its difficult to find what scripts is offending. Any Idea how to know what javascript has offended the minifier?

Comment: Impossible to help you without seeing your code.

Comment: do you have all dependencies spelled out as strings everywhere?

Comment: @akonsu Can you give me an example. what you mean?

Comment: @Stewie The problem is I have 50 javascript files I do not know how to put all of this in stackoverflow. Any tips how to debug this kind of problem?

Comment: here is a page about dependency injection and dependency annotations: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di You basically need to add names of dependencies as strings.

Comment: @akonsu It diffecult to post all the code in stackoverflow angular.module('XUConfess.resources').factory('VoteResource', ['$resource', '$q',  function($resource, $q) {
    some code here
}]); is this what you mean?

Comment: yes. do you have the right annotations like this everywhere? if this does not help then I would try to simplify the code as much as possible to localise the offending code. maybe create a copy of your project and reduce it gradually to a single file or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the problem its one of the javascript I used https://github.com/DerekRies/Angular-Notifications for notification. I tried to look has is code its following the rules I do not know whats wrong with it but anyway when I remove this scripts minify works.

Comment: In [this commit](https://github.com/DerekRies/angular-notifications/commit/5f5668b73b57d283e30b9121c12032538465033d), from 8 hours ago, I can see that the author of the notification module fixed the minification problem that was caused by the `NotificationsCtrl` function declaration.